# Getting "undefined" in node.js when i send data from angular form

Tags: node.js, angular

Whenever I submit data from angular forms I'm receiving undefined in the backend (node.js) even I used body-parser to parse the incoming data.

server.js

```
const express= require("express");
const app=express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const api=require("./server/routes/api");
const cors=require('cors')
 

const port=4440;
app.use(cors())
app.use("/api",api)

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
res.send("hello from server")
})

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("server listening on port"+" "+port)
})
```

Below is the api.js code

api.js

```
const express= require("express");
const router=express.Router();
const User=require("../models/user")
const mongoose= require('mongoose');

const db="mongodb+srv://srihari:dbuser@cluster0.yuykq.mongodb.net/users?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

mongoose.connect(db,{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true},(err)=>{
    if(err){
       console.error("Error" + err)
    }else{
        console.log("DB connected!")
    }

}
)


router.get("/", (req,res)=>{
  res.send("From API route")
})

router.post("/register",(res,req)=>{
    let userData=req.body;
    console.log(userData);
    let user=new User(userData)
    user.save((error,registeredUser) =>{
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            console.log(registeredUser)
        }
    })
})

module.exports=router;
```

angular form code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserserviceService {
  url="http://localhost:4440/api/register";
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
 
  registrationdata(user:any){
    console.log(user);
  return this.http.post<any>(this.url,user);
  }

  // loginData(data:any){
  // return this.http.post<any>(this.)
  // }

}
```

above is the code which is in the front end whenever I'm submitting the form data it is logging in my console but in the backend, I'm getting req.body as "undefined".

Comment: How long is your package.json? Could you share it to read package versions?

Comment: in your code in frontend, what does console.log(user) prints?

Comment: @Akash it is printing user object "{"userName":"uname","password":"password","email":"mail@email.com","address":"hyd"}"

Comment: @Benjamin below is my package.json file
```{
  "name": "angularauth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}```

Comment: I saw the problem and sent my answet. Check it out ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First error I can see it's that your middleware that parse the JSON , is after the API , so it will never arrive there unless the POST was to the / route that it's the only one after it

also you dont need the bodyparser since express already can do that

change your code to something like this

```
const express= require("express");
const app=express();
const api=require("./server/routes/api");
const cors=require('cors')

const port=4440;

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json()) // Express has already a method to parse json
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })) //Allso for the url encoded

app.use("/api",api) //<== Move this line AFTER calling body parsers

app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
res.send("hello from server")
})

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("server listening on port"+" "+port)
})
```

Comment: Hi Manu, i changed the code according the above but still i'm getting undefined.

Comment: @sriharisatyadev are you converting to string the object before sending in the frontend ? Also it's important to specify on the headers that the content you are sending is a json

Comment: yes manu i'm converting it to string while sending it to backend
```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserserviceService {
  url="http://localhost:4440/api/register";
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
 
  registrationdata(user:any){
    const userdata=JSON.stringify(user);
    console.log(userdata);
  return this.http.post<any>(this.url,userdata,{
    headers:new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type":"text/plain"
    })
  });
  }
```

Comment: try to do a post using postman or other http requests program to check if the problem is in the backend or in the frontend

Answer (score 0):

I already saw the problem, and it's a really simple one but hard to see because words are very similar.

You have a typo, this is very common so:

```
router.post("/register",(res,req)=>{
```

Should be:

```
router.post("/register",(req,res)=>{
```

Try that and it should work. Tell me if don't and i'll try to help.